# Bash Script: Variable value obtained from GIT command not populatiing in HTML file

Tags: bash, git

Normally, when a bash variable is passed, the value gets written in a file, but when the variable has a value obtained from git command, the value does not get written in the output html file. Here is  my snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Obtaining Revision Number"
cd /path/to/project/
revision_number= git rev-parse --short HEAD
cat > /path/to/myFile/file.html << EOF
The revision number is "${revision_number}"
EOF
```

Output: The revision number is

Please note that when I use the command in the script using the revision_number it works

```
git show -s --format=%B $revision_number
```

Also, if I use static declaration the value gets passed in the html file

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Obtaining Revision Number"
cd /path/to/project/
firstName=John
cat > /path/to/myFile/file.html << EOF
The revision number is "${firstName}"

EOF
```

Outout: The revision number is John

Comment: What is written to the HTML file instead?

Comment: @mkrieger1 The revision number is .   Basically nothing in place of variable. In the case i use firstName, The revision number is John will be written

Comment: What happens if you paste your script into shellckeck.net and fix all problems it finds?

Comment: `revision_number= git rev-parse --short HEAD` I think there are some `$()` missing here.

Comment: `firstName= John` This doesn't work either, and outputs `bash: John: command not found`. Please use copy and paste to show the _exact_ code you are running, not some approximation with additional bugs in it.

Comment: @Thomas extra space has been fixed in the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the value like this:

```
revision_number=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)
```